# RUBY-RAILS 4 UPDATE MODEL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to update a model on my db. if an user checked the checkbox, it must not be appear again on the view.

I have some view like this:

```
<%= form_tag( riepilogo_path, method: "post", id: "sel") do %>

    <%= hidden_field_tag "sala", params[:sala] %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "spectacle_id", params[:spectacle_id] %>

  <%= hidden_field_tag "num", params[:num] %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Numero</th>

  </tr>
<% for posti in @postis %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= check_box_tag "posti_ids[]", posti.id %></td>
    <td><%=h posti.numero %></td>

  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
<%= submit_tag "OK", id: "sub"%>
<% end %>
```

controller of Postis is something like so:

```
class PostisController < ApplicationController
 def index
    @postis = Posti.where(:stato => "unchecked" , :spectacle_id => params[:spectacle_id] , :hall_num => params[:sala])
  end

def posti_multiple
    @postis = Posti.find(params[:posti_ids])

   end
end
```

In the Posti's model i have attributes: `spectacle_id`, `hall_num`, `seat`(integer) and `stato` (`:default => "unchecked"`).

When he submit, seats be load in `posti_ids[]`. I want to update stato of seats which are present in `posti_ids` from "unchecked" to "checked".

Comment: I try this: @postis.update_column(stato: "checked"), but i have error like so: undefined method `update_column' for #<Array:0xb881584>

Comment: It should be just `Posti.update_column(stato: "checked")`

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment,you have tried to perform `update_column` on an `Array`.So is the error

> undefined method `update_column' for # Array:0xb881584

Here `@postis` returns.You should be giving it like this

```
Posti.update_column(stato: "checked")
```

Comment: I have the same error with Posti.update_column(stato: "checked")